# The fastest way to do a nested loop on the same collection of data

Tags: vb.net

I would like to do this the fastest way. Note that the array contains items of a class and "DoSomething" performs a long task comparing the two elements of the array.

```
    Dim myArray() As String = {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd", "eeee"}
    For i As Integer = myArray.GetLowerBound(0) To myArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j As Integer = myArray.GetLowerBound(0) To i - 1
            DoSomething(myArray(i), myArray(j))
        Next
    Next
```

How I can do?

Comment: There's no magic to it. Nested loops are nested loops. They do what they do. The only way to make your code finish sooner is to optimise the work done on each iteration, i.e. that `DoSomething` method, or else perform the work for multiple iterations in parallel. If you want to do the former then that's a completely different question. If you want to do the latter then do some research on parallelising loops, make an attempt and then post back if you have an actual issue.

Comment: You should double-check that you selection of bounds on `i` and `j` is getting the appropriate coverage.  This may also depend on whether the result of `DoSomething("aaaa", "bbbb")` is the same as the result of `DoSomething("bbbb", "aaaa")`.  Given that `DoSomething` is (by your own statement) your performance bottleneck, you should ensure that it runs the minimum number of times.